# Is there a way to obtain the receipt number of the current bill in erp9

Tags: tally

I have a project. One of the module of the project is 
obtain the current  bill number (the bill still being completed. It is not saved). How can I do that. Can I use the localhost that they provide?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bill is not saved, it means the object was not created within the Tally database. If the object is not created, it's impossible to retrieve it from Tally (I mean, what are you going to point to to obtain the information?), unless you can scrape the information from the user's screen.

UPDATE: I found this and it may be helpful to you.

Identifying the current voucher's Master ID in Voucher Creation Mode:

https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/DeveloperReference/faq/7660.html